# Can you move items made in the Skyrim Creation Kit on PC to the Xbox version?

Tags: modding, xbox, skyrim-modding

I'm a pretty technically illiterate gamer but after several annoying glitches I finally went out and got the PC version of Skyrim. After a little bit of practice I got the hang of transferring my Xbox 360 saves to the PC and vice versa. I've really been enjoying using the console commands and lately after fixing the crashes associated with the DLC have begun to explore the Creation Kit.

I've created several items with custom weight, value, armor rating and multiple custom enchantments. I'd really like to use them on the Xbox, and I know some people will just say to play it on the PC but I just don't enjoy using the keyboard compared to my controller and flat screen TV.

I haven't changed the mesh, design or texture of any of the items just their names and enchantments. Considering Bethesda said they used the Creation Kit to make the game I don't think my custom items are anything the Xbox can't handle. To me it seems like just a matter of getting them over there... Can I do that?

If you know of a video that will show how, that would be awesome. It should be mentioned I'm not willing to do anything to void my Xbox's warranty.

Comment: Plug in your PC to a TV and hook up a controller? :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The Xbox is a closed console without any support for user created content. The situation won't likely change, and even if it did, you'd need a hacked console, which would certainly void your warranty.

Comment: Hacking an XBox is easy and there is nothing to worry about as long as you don't connect to XBL. Never tried altering Skyrim though I'm quite sure it’s possible and would be surprised if there is not already a community dedicated to doing it.

Comment: But since the OP said he doesn't want to void the warranty, hacking the console isn't really an option.

Comment: It is he just needs to google around a bit.

Comment: @ClassicThunder This is pretty old but he clearly stated he is not willing to void his warranty. Modifying his console will void his warranty.